# How to build and source from Eclipse

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, build, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on a .cpp file in Eclipse (called myownstuff.cpp which I put in the turtlesim package). Whenever I want to run it, I have to type this in the console:

```
catkin build turtlesim
source devel/setup.bash
rosrun turtlesim myownstuff
```

Is it possible to do (parts of) these commands in Eclipse? I tried some options related to building and sourcing, but they don't seem to work. Any help or ideas are welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329341/how-to-build-and-source-from-eclipse/) by [martijn_](https://answers.ros.org/users/44050/martijn_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you may look how to create the eclipse project und thn you can start it from inside

http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-26**:
[Here's the direct link to Eclipse](https://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse)